# Determine if Firebug's console.log() was called anywhere on a page

Tags: javascript, css, debugging, firebug

I'd like to be able to programmatically add a class of `console` to the `<body>` tag if Firebug's `console.log()` was called anywhere on a page. Then I could put some obnoxious message on the screen to remind me not to deploy code with those statements still in it.

The very similar to Eric Meyer's [Diagnostic CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/diagnostics/).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Hehehe. It's an easy mistake to make, isn't it.

- Option 1: Always write `if(window.console) console.log(...);` instead of just `console.log(..);`
- Option 2:

  ```
  function mydebug(thingtodebug) {
      if(window.console) console.log(thingtodebug);
  }
  ```

..then always use `mydebug()` instead of `console.log();`. You could include an `else` clause that throws up an alert box if console isn't defined.

- Option 3:

  ```
  if(!window.console) {
      var console={
          log : function() {alert("Don't call console.log");}
      }
  }
  ```

...this will do pretty much exactly what you're asking.

The trouble is that all these options involve including extra code in your live system just to help you avoid embarrassment. (and of course, it'd be even more embarrassing if you miss that alert box!)

If you want to avoid this, a better solution might be to have a separate script that scans your code for any occurrences of `console.log`. You could run this script as part of your deployment process.

Hope that helps.

Comment: `if (console)` will throw an error if it's not loaded, use `if (window.console)`

Comment: Those are acceptable solutions, but don't forget that you will lose capabilities like line-reporting (console.debug, console.error) because the line will always come up as line 2 (or whatever line it was on in the function). You also won't be able to pass in a variable number of arguments like: console.log(var1, var2, var3);

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (using jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var body = $('body'),
      console = window.console;

  console.debug = function() {
    if (!body.hasClass('console')) {
      body.addClass('console');
      console.debug = oldDebug;
    }
  }

  console.debug('foo');
});
```

It will only add the class the first time our custom function is called. Then it sets console.debug to the original function.
That's the cool thing with javascript, you can override nearly everything :)

Comment: Worth pointing out this code uses jQuery. Not a problem, but worth knowing in case someone tries it and it doesn't work.

Comment: Sure. Added it to my answer. Sometimes I just forget that ;-)

Comment: Added a question for a pure-javascript approach:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4091538/how-to-find-out-which-javascripts-are-loaded-in-javascript

Comment: Let me remind you that this approach will only help you if you execute every path of code as you are testing. This is not very robust, you may very well get an error from a client doing something you didn't test. I would just run grep looking for console. inside js and html files before checking code into source control, (or deploying it if you don't use source control). Again, why would you use a pure js approach? Run a "find in files".

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple. Just override the default console object with your own:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Console Test</title>
        <script>
            var oldConsole = (typeof window.console === "object") ? window.console : null;
            var console = {
                log: function() {
                    oldConsole.log(arguments);
                    document.body.className = "console";
                    alert('applied class');
                }
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="click me" onclick="console.log('this is a test');">
    </body>
</html>
```

[Live example.](http://jsbin.com/ozura3/edit)